# Divide by zero error encountered. When Unıon Code

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

i am pulling data to excel from sql server
Like : https://prnt.sc/to9ntg
but ı have to problem now,
because of Divide by zero error encountered
ı am login to sql and

```
---select * from [dbo].[TLP_CEK]

SELECT * FROM TLP
UNION 
SELECT * FROM TLP_S1
UNION 
SELECT * FROM TLP_S2
```

sql returning to me

```
Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Divide by zero error encountered.
```

how can i fix this i am just  getting data(columns,tables)  sql-->to Excel

Comment: Can you run each if those selects separately? Are those TLPs views?

Comment: This is not caused by the `union`, but rather by the nature of the object `TLP`, or `TLP_S1`, or `TLP_S2`. One or more of them is either a view, or a table with a computed column When you select from them, SQL evaluates the expressions within the view (or computed columns) to generate the output data. At least one of those expressions is a division of some number over some other number, where the second number is zero. Look at the definitions of those objects to find somewhere that a division is occuring.